# Discord Bot Reminder or Alarm

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm looking for some way to make my Discord bot say a message on a channel every day at 15:00 (As if it were a reminder or an alarm). I've been searching for codes on GitHub but I can't find one that works well with what I'm looking for. Most of the code that I have found works like this and it is difficult to get the bot to send the message at the exact time and that the bot is activated 24 hours a day so that it does not cancel. Code:

```
let targetChannel = message.guild.channels.get("ChannelID")
                    if (targetChannel) targetChannel.send("**Hello**").then(m => {m.delete(86400000).then(m => {m.edit("Editing...");
 message.channel.send('Hello') 
});
});
}
```

Comment: Do look into `setInterval()` to loop a function every x amount of time, checking if it is currently your desired time before sending a message to a specific channel. As for keeping your bot online (and thus the code running), you will need to keep your host device running, or use/pay for an online hosting service.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```js
setInterval(() => {
  const date = new Date(); // today
  if (date.getHours() === 15 && date.getMinutes() === 0) {
    const targetChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.get('ChannelID');
    if (targetChannel)
      targetChannel
      .send('**Hello**')
      .then((m) => {
        m.delete(86400000);
      })
      .then((m) => {
        m.edit('Editing...');
      });
    message.channel.send('Hello');
  }
}, 60000); // check every minute
```

Comment: I've tried your way and it doesn't work for me. I have modified your code like this and it works for me but at the time you have to send the message it sends it 4 times. If you can help me with that thank you.
Code:

`setInterval(() => {
  const date = new Date().toLocaleTimeString().slice(0, 5); // today
  if (date === "12:24") {
message.channel.send("Hello");
}
}, 60000);`

Comment: I don't know whether your solution works. Please try `if (date.getHours() === 14 && date.getMinutes() === 33)` (replace the hours and minutes there). It works totally fine.

Comment: Which version of NodeJS are you using?

Comment: I have tried that way and it keeps sending me more than 1 message

Comment: Have you changed the interval value?

Comment: No it's still 1 minute

Comment: `setInterval(() => {
  var currentdate = new Date(); 
  var datetime = "Date Time: " + currentdate.getDate() + "/"
    + (currentdate.getMonth()+1)  + "/" 
    + currentdate.getFullYear() + " @ "  
    + currentdate.getHours() + ":"  
  if (currentdate.getHours() === 14 && currentdate.getMinutes() === 13) {
   
    let targetChannel = message.guild.channels.get("Channel_ID")
                    if (targetChannel) targetChannel.send("Ok");
  }
}, 120000); // check every 2 minutes`

Comment: Your code contains multiple syntax errors and unlogic stuff. I have corrected it and it works fine: `setInterval(() => {
    var currentdate = new Date();

    if (currentdate.getHours() === 16 && currentdate.getMinutes() === 21) {
        let targetChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.get('Channel_ID');
        if (targetChannel) targetChannel.send('Ok');
    }
}, 60000);

`

Comment: Now he does nothing when the time comes. F XD

Comment: Have you updated the hours and minutes? And have you entered the correct channel id?

Comment: Yes, I have set the time and the channel well

Comment: Which NodeJS Version and discord.js Version are you using?